# Set Partitioning Formulation of PDPTW

Tags: vehicle-routing, set-covering

I am studying a paper on a Pickup Dropoff Problem with Time Window (https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/trsc.1090.0272 ). The three index formulation is straightforward. The formulation is as follows:

[image]
[image]

However, there is a set partitioning formulation of the problem, that works with a set of all feasible routes that satisfy all PDPTW constraints, plus a constraint that limits that each node will be covered by only one route. My question is how am I going to generate those routes for this set partitioning problem? Should I generate all possible route witt all vertices in the network? Below is the set patitining formulation:

[image]

Comment: Search phrase: "column generation"

Comment: For an open source python library with such formulations, checkout [vrpy](https://github.com/Kuifje02/vrpy)